# collapse cell array to text matlab

Tags: matlab

it's a basic question I guess (but I'm new to Matlab), but given:

```
>> class(motifIndexAfterThresholds)
ans =
    'double'
```

with :

```
16
8037
14340
21091
27903
34082
```

as the contents of that variable

I hoped to print to the same line on the matlab console the contents of that variable and some other output:

```
fprintf('With threshold set to %d, %d motifs found at positions %f.\n',threshold,length(motifIndexAfterThresholds), motifIndexAfterThresholds);
```

When I do this however, I'm getting more than one line of output:

```
With threshold set to 800, 6 motifs found at positions 16.000000.
With threshold set to 8037, 14340 motifs found at positions 21091.000000.
With threshold set to 27903, 34082 motifs found at positions
```

Can someone share the method for collapsing this double array to a single line of text that I can display on the Matlab console please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `num2str` function that is builtin MATLAB. Modify your code as below:

```
strThresholds = num2str(motifIndexAfterThresholds.', '%f, '); % Transpose used here since you need to make sure that motifIndexAfterThresholds is a row vector
fprintf('With threshold set to %d, %d motifs found at positions %s.\n',threshold,length(motifIndexAfterThresholds), strThresholds);
```

The `num2str` function will convert your vector to a string with the specified format. So for your given example,

```
strThresholds = '16.000000,  8037.000000, 14340.000000, 21091.000000, 27903.000000, 34082.000000,'
```

You could definitely edit the format string used in the `num2str` funcion to suit your needs. I would suggest using `%d` since you have integers in your vector

Comment: Thank you very much anyanwu!  That does it - but one quick last question, you added a dot and quote mark to the end of the motifIndexAfterThresholds variable, what does that do syntactically? (if I leave it out, the output seems radically different) . (is that the transpose you mentioned?)

Comment: That is the method to transpose a matrix. Please see the comment I wrote on that line. You need to make sure that the `motifIndexAfterThresholds` variable is a row vector. Since it is a column vector in your case, I transposed it